# jQuery .play() doesn't work on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I'm using JQuery and I tried this code

```
<video id="videoPopUp1" poster="img/xxx.png">
       <source src="video/xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

$('#playBtn1').click(function () {
    $("#playBtn1").hide();
    $('#videoPopUp1').get(0).play();
});

$('#videoPopUp1').click(function () {
    if (this.paused == false) {
       this.pause();
       $('#playBtn1').show()
  } else {
       this.play();
       $('#playBtn1').hide()
    }
});
```

but on Iphone (Safari, iOS 9.3.1) and Ipad (Safari, 8.1.2) it doesn't work. It works fine on all other browsers/devices (Chrome, Firefox, android, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[That does not work because autoplay (and preloading) is disabled in safari on iOS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, **preload and autoplay are disabled**.

That means that you will always need "User Interaction" to start video playback.