# jQuery only working not chrome, not safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery function that makes video play and pause on hover. It is working fine on Chrome, but not at all on Safari. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks so much!!

```
$(function(){
  $("video").hover(function(){
    this.play();
    },function(){
   this.pause()
  });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739102/jquery-play-doesnt-work-on-mobile-safari

Comment: Thanks. It isn't solely a mobile issue, though. It isn't working on desktop Safari either...

Comment: Same -- Safari in general doesn't support preload and autoplay.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on another way to do it that will work on all browsers? Thanks again.

Comment: ^^ try adding it after the page loads using document.addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded,()=>{“function...”})

Comment: Also assuming you are using video tags make sure audio IS muted <video autoplay muted>

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding the eventListener, but the console is telling me that DOMContentLoaded is not defined...? Sorry... I'm pretty new to this....