# jQuery on hover sound code is not working on safari browser

Tags: jquery

My jQuery Code is not working on Safari Browser.

```
jQuery("#hoveraudio").hover(function(){
    players.play();
        },
 function(){
        players.load();
    });
```

i'm using this code to play a sound on hovering a specific area. on all the browsers and phones its working perfectly but on the safari browsers and iphones its not working...
please help me to fix it.

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739167/17033432

Comment: does click works instead of hover?

Comment: The user needs to interact with the page before you can play a sound. Hovering is not considered enough of an action for this to happen. It would need to be done under a click event, for example.